# Label GNOME workspaces?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, workspaces, gnome-shell-extension

How do I attach a label to each workspace in GNOME? E.g. work, study, plan, etc.

Comment: Some of the workspace gnome shell extensions let you edit labels.  I'm not sure if anything uses them?